# Insert date with sed command

Tags: date, unix, sed

I'm having trouble inserting the output from UNIX date into a sed replace command.  I have tried a number of delimiters but the command keeps failing with "sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command".  I presume this is because the output of date has semicolons.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
sed -i '70 s!CDATE!'`date`'!g' combined_today.cdl
```

`date
Mon May 29 18:40:42 UTC 2017`

Answer (score 3):

The spaces in date‘s output are the problem, they split your sed script into several parts.

I suggest to add `"`:

```
sed -i '70 s!CDATE!'"`date`"'!g' combined_today.cdl
```

or

```
sed -i "70 s/CDATE/$(date)/g" combined_today.cdl
```

Comment: This works!  I've been going back and forth for an hour or so with this, thanks so much!